# Error : Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'NativeReanimated' could not be found

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I followed this tutorial https://medium.com/@ritikjain1272/making-drawer-navigator-and-a-splash-screen-on-your-react-native-app-2fb561ee17f1 And I have been able to work on several Mobile Apps in the past. Which compiled to APK and uploaded to playstore, but this was in the past.

Trying since today and its been very impossible to get it to work as the very usual.
I keep getting this Error

> Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...):
> 'NativeReanimated' could not be found. Verify that a module by this
> name is registered in the native binary.

My code is looking like this for App.js

```
import {createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons';

import Splash from './src/Splash';
import Login from './src/Login';
import Register from './src/Register';
import Dashboard from './src/Dashboard';
import InstantMessage from './src/InstantMessage';

const LoginNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  'Login': {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerLeft: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{marginLeft: 20}}
          onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
          <Icon name="menu" size={12} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    }),
  },
});

const RegisterNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  'Register': {
    screen: Register,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerLeft: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{marginLeft: 20}}
          onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
          <Icon name="menu" size={12} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    }),
  },
});

const DashboardNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  'Home': {
    screen: Dashboard,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerLeft: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{marginLeft: 20}}
          onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
          <Icon name="menu" size={12} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    }),
  },
});

const InstantMessageNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  'Instant Message': {
    screen: InstantMessage,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerLeft: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{marginLeft: 20}}
          onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
          <Icon name="menu" size={12} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    }),
  },
});


const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({

  Dashboard: {
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerIcon: (
        <Image
          source={{uri: 'asset:/icons/megaphone.png'}}
          style={{width: 21, height: 21}}
        />
      ),
      drawerLabel: 'Home',
    },
    screen: DashboardNavigator,
  },

  InstantMessage: {
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerIcon: (
        <Image
          source={{uri: 'asset:/icons/megaphone.png'}}
          style={{width: 21, height: 21}}
        />
      ),
      drawerLabel: 'Messages',
    },
    screen: DashboardNavigator,
  },
});



const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Splash: {screen: Splash},
    Login: {screen: Login},
    Drawer: {screen: DrawerNavigator},
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Splash',
  },
);

const App = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator);
export default App;
```

And package.json is looking like this

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxxxxx",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.9.8",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-hr": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-hr-component": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.16.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.3",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.6.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.12.10",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "25.5.1",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "25.5.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

What Can I be possibly doing wrong? I honestly need help. This is a React Native CLI project.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/1642?

Comment: @Rohit, saw that, i got confused implementing that. is there something I need to do. What I did and packages i installed is what I show on here. 

I followed that tutorial step by step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by downgrading **react-native-reanimated**

If your using npm do this:

```
npm install react-native-reanimated@1.9.9
```

if your using yarn do this:

```
yarn upgrade react-native-reanimated@1.9.9
```

if you want to do it manually change the version **react-native-reanimated** to `react-native-reanimated: ^1.9.9` in `package.json` then run `npm install` or `yarn add`

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue.

You need to install both Libraries with these Versions

```
react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2"
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.11.4"
```

This absolutely works for me

Comment: Adding a reference would improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue "Image Loader" in place of "NativeReanimated"
I just stopped the debugger and did the Hard reload with an empty catch on the chrome browser.
It works fine then

[image]